# Lost luggage by Vueling, how to claim compensation?

Tags: luggage, vueling

Vueling lost my luggage. I'm trying to claim compensation for everything I had to buy for my whole week without luggage.

However I did not find out how.

There's a page https://www.vueling.com/en/vueling-services/more-vueling-services/damaged-and-delayed-baggage
that even cite the case: Expenses incurred as a result of delayed baggage (any expenditure on basic necessities)

However the "Claim" button only leads to a chatbot that ends in "Check the status of your luggage" and I can never claim anything.

I called their customer service, they just told me to use the same chatbot. But that they would send me an email so I can send screenshot of errors. They did not.

The deadline (21 days) is drawing near: I got 3 days left.

Does anyone know of another way, a service, a mail, to do this ? I've seen some stuff (more generic not related to Vueling) suggesting that I should send a physical mail, but have not seen any address of Vueling where I could send such mail ?

Is there maybe a company that I could pay to do such things in my stead ? I looked around but only found services for canceled flights.

I am in France. The flight was France to Germany.

Note: I still haven't got my bag yet, it will be officially lost at the time the deadline for compensation expires.

Update: Now they told me that I can't make the claim until I have my bag. Which I definitely won't have before the 21 days expire.

Comment: As far as I know, there’s no deadline for you to claim (at least nothing as short as 21 days). 21 days is usually the point where “delayed” becomes “lost” (don’t remember whether that’s in the Montreal Convention or somewhere else).

Comment: If you want a physical address to send registered mail, societe.com will give it to you (in Spain)

Comment: For reference, the [Montreal Convention](https://www.iata.org/contentassets/fb1137ff561a4819a2d38f3db7308758/mc99-full-text.pdf) which governs compensation for issues related to luggage on lost international flights. There is no deadline for claiming compensation for expenditure in case of delay (article 19), or if the baggage is lost. There are deadlines to notify them of the missing luggage (which I suppose you did) and for claims about damage to your luggage (which, when baggage is delayed, is 21 days after you get it).

Comment: It’s probably the easiest path to wait for them to declare it lost, then you can claim for both your expenses and for the lost luggage at the same time.

Comment: Some relevant reading: https://www.forbes.com/advisor/credit-cards/travel-rewards/montreal-convention-luggage/

Answer (score 2):

Vueling policy is that:

- either they get your luggage back and they reimburse you for claimed expenses (but you can only claim it after you get it back)
- or they pay for the lost luggage
  But not both. (Which seem illegal ?)

They also pay for the lost luggage according to weight (which is not normal in the Montreal convention, and with ridiculously low value per kilo).